# Can using R output image as a stream binary and read by Java

Tags: r

I plot an image from R and i want output this image as binary stream and we can read image from that stream using Java . Is it possible ??

Comment: Aren't tiff and png files binary streams?

Comment: whatever , as long as binary stream and can read by java stream reader

Answer (score 0):

You can output the actual image in R and then read the image to start streaming it to you client in Java.

Java code to stream the image

```
String path =  "myimage.png";                       
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
```

Comment: Thanks but I want directly read from stream not via file system :)